# catkin_make missing after groovy upgrade from fuego

Tags: catkin-make, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I upgraded my Ubuntu precise fuego installation to groovy and it seems that some of the catkin tools are missing.
I did this because I was trying to follow a tutorial and got lost trying to figure out the fuego equivalents.

The command that I used was
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full

It seems that I only have catkin_create_pkg, catkin_find_pkg, catkin_generate_changelog, catkin_tag_changelog and catkin_test_changelog commands.

I am really not much of a Linux admin so I don't even know how to remove ROS and start over so any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101401/catkin_make-missing-after-groovy-upgrade-from-fuego/) by [flb](https://answers.ros.org/users/8821/flb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2013-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need run this command on each new terminal (or add it to your `~/.bashrc` file):

```
$ source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
```

This adds the ROS groovy installation to your local terminal environment and should allow you to use `catkin_make` as long as you have `ros-groovy-catkin` installed (it should be installed from `ros-groovy-desktop-full`).

The reason you can see the other `catkin_*` functions you listed is because they are provided in a distro agnostic Python package, `python-catkin-pkg`, which is in your environment regardless of your ROS distro you are using.

P.S. The version of ROS before Groovy was Fuerte. :)

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flb](https://answers.ros.org/users/8821/flb/) on 2013-11-14**:
That worked perfectly.  I found the original fuerte setup command in my .bashrc and replaced it with groovy.

**Comment by [flb](https://answers.ros.org/users/8821/flb/) on 2013-11-14**:
I now have /opt/ros/fuerte and /opt/ros/groovy
Can I remove the fuerte tree?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-11-14**:
`sudo apt-get remove ros-fuerte-*` should work I think.

**Comment by [flb](https://answers.ros.org/users/8821/flb/) on 2013-11-15**:
Perfect! Thanks!
I wish I could add more votes for you.